# materialize carousel unexpected vertical lines in edge browser

Tags: javascript, carousel, materialize

I'm using materialize carousel in my page with fullWidth parameter. In chrome it is working well but in edge, there are some vertical lines, which is not related to any element in page.
The lines are showing when carousel played and just in right side element.

[vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsxzh.png)

It is also not working at offical demo for edge browser. Special Options example not working.
http://materializecss.com/carousel.html

Comment: I can't reproduce. Maybe it's time to update your graphics hardware ..?

Comment: @Teemu It is not working also at another computers.

Comment: The page linked at materializecss.com works for me in Edge, both on a desktop device and on a phone, no "vertical lines" can be seen ...

Comment: @Teemu thanks for testing. At demo there is background problem like that https://ibb.co/cms7eG . No vertical lines but background is not fully viewing.

Comment: Bingo! I didn't notice the background issue, just checked the image carousels on that page. It looks like they have difficulties with preventing selection correctly on Edge when dragging, maybe your issue is related ..?

Comment: thanks I'll try to find problem, I think its width is not setting truly..